# How can I change the location of the International Input's Composition Window programmatically?

Tags: cocoa

I am working on an application which allows the user to perform input via international keyboard on a Mac. However, the Composition window displayed by the Mac OS for the user to type in the characters is located outside my application's view. I need to move the location of the composition window so that it overlaps the edit window inside my application. Please let me know if there is a way this can be done programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

The only (non-hacky) way to move windows that don't belong to you is to use the [Accessibility Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXIntro/cocoaAXintro.html). You'll want to convert your view frame's coordinates to screen coordinates, then use the Accessibility API to move the window to that screen-coordinate-based frame.

Comment: Please let me know if there is an API which I can use to get a handle to the Input method's Composition window, so that I can move it to its new location ?

Comment: That's exactly what I just did.

Comment: Please let me know the name of this API

Comment: *Read the answer I posted and follow the link.* How can you expect help if you're unwilling to read?

Comment: I apologize as I missed seeing the link. I will check it out .Thanks

Comment: hi Joshua: I implemented the NSTextInputClient protocol in my View and now I am able to capture the keystrokes from the international keyboard. However,as a result of implementation of this protocol, the system has disabled the display of the international input's composition window. As a result of this the user cannot see the characters as they are being typed (before the Enter key is pressed). Please let me know if there is a way to enable the display of this composition window. Thanks in advance for your help.